# Change color inside circle

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to change color inside circle example:(two color) from red to blue and blue to red.
I tried this using if else but it didn't work for me.

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
// for canvas size
var window_width = window.innerWidth;
var window_height = window.innerHeight;

canvas.width = window_width;
canvas.height = window_height;
let hit_counter = 0;

// object is created using class
class Circle {
  constructor(xpos, ypos, radius, speed, color, text) {
    this.position_x = xpos;
    this.position_y = ypos;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.dx = 1 * this.speed;
    this.dy = 1 * this.speed;
    this.text = text;
    this.color = color;
  }

  // creating circle
  draw(context) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.strokeStyle = this.color;
    context.fillText(this.text, this.position_x, this.position_y);
    context.textAlign = "center";
    context.textBaseline = "middle"
    context.font = "20px Arial";
    context.lineWidth = 5;
    context.arc(this.position_x, this.position_y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    context.stroke();
    context.closePath();
  }

  update() {
    this.text = hit_counter;
    context.clearRect(0, 0, window_width, window_height)
    this.draw(context);

    if ((this.position_x + this.radius) > window_width) {
      this.dx = -this.dx;
      hit_counter++;
    }

    if ((this.position_x - this.radius) < 0) {
      this.dx = -this.dx;
      hit_counter++;
    }

    if ((this.position_y - this.radius) < 0) {
      this.dy = -this.dy;
      hit_counter++;
    }

    if ((this.position_y + this.radius) > window_height) {
      this.dy = -this.dy;
      hit_counter++;
    }

    this.position_x += this.dx;
    this.position_y += this.dy;
  }
}

let my_circle = new Circle(100, 100, 50, 3, 'Black', hit_counter);

let updateCircle = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(updateCircle);
  my_circle.update();

}

updateCircle();

//for color
function changeColor(event) {
  var coloorr = event.value;
  canvas.style.background = coloorr;

}

// I tried it in bllk function but it didn't work for me.     
function bllk() {
  canvas.style.background = "black";
  context.fillStyle = "blue";
  // I tried it in bllk function but it didn't work for me.
  // setInterval(() => {
  //     if(context.fillStyle=="blue"){
  //         context.fillStyle=red;
  //         context.fill();
  //     }else if(context.fillStyle=="red"){
  //         context.fillStyle=blue;
  //         context.fill();
  //     }else if(context.fillStyle=="blue"){
  //         context.fillStyle=red;
  //         context.fill();
  //     }
  // }, 1000);

}
```

```html
<!-- On clicking button Hi How to apply two color one by one to the numbers inside the circle ? I tried it in bllk function but it didn't work for me. -->
<button onclick="bllk()">Hi</button>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: What do you mean by two color? ... your function bllk is applying a background to the canvas  and fillStyle

Comment: On clicking button Hi I want to change color inside circle example:(two color) from red to blue and blue to red. I tried this using if else but it didn't work for me. Please Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code needed a little upgrade:

- decoupling variables from each other & the global space
- adding some internal attributes & methods to the circle

Now it's possible to change the background color of the canvas, the outline and text of the circle, and the background of the circle separataley.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
// for canvas size
const window_width = window.innerWidth;
const window_height = window.innerHeight;

canvas.width = window_width;
canvas.height = window_height;

// object is created using class
class Circle {
  constructor(xpos, ypos, radius, speed, color, text) {
    this.position_x = xpos;
    this.position_y = ypos;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.dx = 1 * this.speed;
    this.dy = 1 * this.speed;
    this.text = text;
    this.color = color;
    this.fillColor = "white" // added as a default value
    this.hit_counter = 0
  }

  // outline & text in circle
  drawOutline({
    ctx
  }) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color
    ctx.fillText(this.text, this.position_x, this.position_y);
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle"
    ctx.font = "20px Arial";
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.arc(this.position_x, this.position_y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
  }

  // background of the circle
  drawFill({
    ctx,
    color
  }) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.fillColor
    ctx.arc(this.position_x, this.position_y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }

  // drawing the circle from two pieces
  draw(ctx) {
    this.drawFill({
      ctx
    })
    this.drawOutline({
      ctx
    })
  }

  // color change function
  setColor({
    outline,
    fill
  }) {
    this.color = outline
    this.fillColor = fill
  }

  update(ctx) {
    this.text = this.hit_counter;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, window_width, window_height)
    this.draw(context);

    if ((this.position_x + this.radius) > window_width) {
      this.dx = -this.dx;
      this.hit_counter++;
    }

    if ((this.position_x - this.radius) < 0) {
      this.dx = -this.dx;
      this.hit_counter++;
    }

    if ((this.position_y - this.radius) < 0) {
      this.dy = -this.dy;
      this.hit_counter++;
    }

    if ((this.position_y + this.radius) > window_height) {
      this.dy = -this.dy;
      this.hit_counter++;
    }

    this.position_x += this.dx;
    this.position_y += this.dy;
  }
}

const my_circle = new Circle(100, 100, 50, 3, 'Black');

const updateCircle = function(ctx) {
  requestAnimationFrame(() => updateCircle(ctx));
  my_circle.update(ctx);
}

updateCircle(context);

// I tried it in bllk function but it didn't work for me.     
function bllk1() {
  canvas.style.background = "black";
  my_circle.setColor({
    outline: "red",
    fill: "yellow"
  })
}

function bllk() {
  canvas.style.background = "black";
  my_circle.setColor({
    outline: "black",
    fill: "blue"
  })
  setInterval(() => {
    const fill = my_circle.fillColor === "blue" ? "red" : "blue"
    my_circle.setColor({
      outline: "black",
      fill,
    })
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<!-- On clicking button Hi How to apply two color one by one to the numbers inside the circle ? I tried it in bllk function but it didn't work for me. -->
<button onclick="bllk()">Hi</button>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: On clicking button Hi I want to change color inside the circle Example:(two colors) from changing red to blue and blue to red color continuously . I tried this using if else but it didn't work for me. Please Answer  How to do that?

Comment: Why the `{ ctx }` Why those brackets?? also on `drawFill` the color param is not used

Comment: @HelderSepulveda with `drawFill` you are right - the `color` is not used, you can safely ignore that. `{ ctx }` - the curly braces are needed as they mean "key of an object" (so, the function expects something like: `{ ctx: "somevalue" }`

Comment: I see no need for the curly braces there, you can do it just like in your `draw(ctx)`

Comment: `function bllk() {
  canvas.style.background = "black";
 
  my_circle.setColor({
    outline: "black",
    fill: "blue"
    
  })
  setInterval(() => {
    if (fill = "blue") {
      my_circle.setColor({
        outline: "black",
        fill: "red"
        
      })
    } else if(fill = "red"){
      my_circle.setColor({
        outline: "black",
        fill: "blue"
        
      })
    }
  }, 1000);
}`  I want to change color inside circle example:(two color) from red to blue and blue to red.
I tried this using if else but it didn't work for me. How to do that?

Comment: @tpler your code has errors, that's why it did not work. I edited the snippet - now it toggles between red and blue (1000 ms) if you click on `Hi`

Comment: Thank you so much... Is it possible to increase and decrease the font size of number inside the circle? If yes, Then Please Answer that also.. in your snippet.

Comment: @tpler - please, start a new question for that, and get the answer there. Before that, I would suggest that you try to copy the `setColor` method of the `Circle` class, rename it and try to change the font size yourself using that as a "template".

Comment: New question.. Please Answer This link also.. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70946992/i-want-to-increase-and-decrease-the-font-size-and-brightness-of-number-inside-th)

Comment: New question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70946992/i-want-to-increase-and-decrease-the-font-size-and-brightness-of-number-inside-th)

Answer (score 0):

I simplified your code to just focus on what you asked on the comments:
`changing red to blue and blue to red color continuously`
To focus on that specific problem we don't need the Circle moving or the collisions with the borders, in the future when you are asking a question you should do the same, provide a minimal example, remove everything else that is not specifically related to your problem.

To solve your issue we can pass a colors parameter to the draw function, that way we let it know what colors to use for the circle and the text, or anything you might want to add in the future.
See code sample below:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = canvas.height = 100;

class Circle {
  draw(xpos, ypos, radius, colors) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(xpos, ypos, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);   
    context.fillStyle = colors.circle;
    context.fill();
    
    context.beginPath();
    context.font = "20px Arial";
    context.fillStyle = colors.text;
    context.fillText("0", xpos, ypos);  
  }
}

let my_circle = new Circle();
let colors = {text:"red", circle:"blue"};

let updateCircle = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(updateCircle);
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  my_circle.draw(50, 50, 20, colors);
}
updateCircle();

setInterval(() => {
  if (colors.text == "blue") {
    colors = {text:"red", circle:"blue"};
  } else {
    colors = {text:"blue", circle:"red"};
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```