# I want to increase and decrease the font size and brightness of number inside the circle. How to do that?

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, html5-canvas

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
// for canvas size
const window_width = window.innerWidth;
const window_height = window.innerHeight;

canvas.width = window_width;
canvas.height = window_height;

// object is created using class
class Circle {
  constructor(xpos, ypos, radius, speed, color, text) {
    this.position_x = xpos;
    this.position_y = ypos;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.dx = 1 * this.speed;
    this.dy = 1 * this.speed;
    this.text = text;
    this.color = color;
    this.fillColor = "white" // added as a default value
    this.hit_counter = 0
  }

  // outline & text in circle
  drawOutline({
    ctx
  }) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color
    ctx.fillText(this.text, this.position_x, this.position_y);
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle"
    ctx.font = "20px Arial";
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.arc(this.position_x, this.position_y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
//I want to increase and decrease the font size and brightness of number inside the circle. How to do that?
  // background of the circle
  drawFill({
    ctx,
    color
  }) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.fillColor
    ctx.arc(this.position_x, this.position_y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
//I want to increase and decrease the font size and brightness of number inside the circle. How to do that?
  // drawing the circle from two pieces
  draw(ctx) {
    this.drawFill({
      ctx
    })
    this.drawOutline({
      ctx
    })
  }
//I want to increase and decrease the font size and brightness of number inside the circle. How to do that?
  // color change function
  setColor({
    outline,
    fill
  }) {
    this.color = outline
    this.fillColor = fill
  }

//I want to increase and decrease the font size and brightness of number inside the circle. How to do that?
  update(ctx) {
    this.text = this.hit_counter;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, window_width, window_height)
    this.draw(context);

    if ((this.position_x + this.radius) > window_width) {
      this.dx = -this.dx;
      this.hit_counter++;
    }

    if ((this.position_x - this.radius) < 0) {
      this.dx = -this.dx;
      this.hit_counter++;
    }

    if ((this.position_y - this.radius) < 0) {
      this.dy = -this.dy;
      this.hit_counter++;
    }

    if ((this.position_y + this.radius) > window_height) {
      this.dy = -this.dy;
      this.hit_counter++;
    }

    this.position_x += this.dx;
    this.position_y += this.dy;
  }
}
//I want to increase and decrease the font size and brightness of number inside the circle. How to do that?
const my_circle = new Circle(100, 100, 50, 3, 'Black');

const updateCircle = function(ctx) {
  requestAnimationFrame(() => updateCircle(ctx));
  my_circle.update(ctx);
}

updateCircle(context);

document.getElementById("inc").addEventListener("click", increment);

function increment() {
  //I want to increase and decrease the font size and brightness of number inside the circle. How to do that?
}
document.getElementById("dec").addEventListener("click", decrement);

function decrement() {
  //I want to increase and decrease the font size and brightness of number inside the circle. How to do that?
}

document.getElementById("bri").addEventListener("click", briincrement);

function briincrement() {
  //I want to increase and decrease the font size and brightness of number inside the circle. How to do that?
}
document.getElementById("bridec").addEventListener("click", bridecrement);

function bridecrement() {
  //I want to increase and decrease the font size and brightness of number inside the circle. How to do that?
}
```

```html
<button id="inc">Font +</button>
    <button id="dec">Font -</button>
    <button id="bri">Font brightness +</button>
    <button id="bridec">Font brightness -</button>

    
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from your own code, the size of text written onto a canvas is controlled by the `.font` property.

```
ctx.font = "20px Arial";
```

So in order to change the font size we need to alter the 20 inside the string. This can be done by making it a class variable of your circle class:

```
this.fontSize = 20;
```

and the `drawOutline()` method needs a little modification to take use of this variable:

```
ctx.font = this.fontSize + "px Arial";
```

Now all you have to do is vary the value of fontSize of a Circle instance using the corresponding buttons:

```
document.getElementById("inc").addEventListener("click", increment);
function increment() {
    my_circle.fontSize++;
}

document.getElementById("dec").addEventListener("click", decrement);
function decrement() {
    if (my_circle.fontSize - 1 >= 0) {
        my_circle.fontSize--;
    }
}
```

The brightness of the font can be controlled in a similar way. For simplicity let's use the CanvasRenderingContext2D `.globalAlpha` property, which controls the opacity of drawing operations. Let's give your class another propety:

```
this.textAlpha = 1.0;
```

Text is written using the `.fillText()` method. That means we need to modify the global alpha just before writing text and reset it to 1 afterwards:

```
ctx.globalAlpha = this.textAlpha;
ctx.fillText(this.text, this.position_x, this.position_y);
ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
```

After adding a similar logic for the brightness buttons we'll come up with this:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
// for canvas size
const window_width = window.innerWidth;
const window_height = window.innerHeight;

canvas.width = window_width;
canvas.height = window_height;

// object is created using class
class Circle {
  constructor(xpos, ypos, radius, speed, color, text) {
    this.position_x = xpos;
    this.position_y = ypos;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.dx = 1 * this.speed;
    this.dy = 1 * this.speed;
    this.text = text;
    this.color = color;
    this.fontSize = 20;
    this.textAlpha = 1.0;
    this.fillColor = "white" // added as a default value
    this.hit_counter = 0
  }

  // outline & text in circle
  drawOutline({
    ctx
  }) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color
    ctx.globalAlpha = this.textAlpha;
    ctx.fillText(this.text, this.position_x, this.position_y);
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle"
    ctx.font = this.fontSize + "px Arial";

    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.arc(this.position_x, this.position_y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
  //I want to increase and decrease the font size and brightness of number inside the circle. How to do that?
  // background of the circle
  drawFill({
    ctx,
    color
  }) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.fillColor
    ctx.arc(this.position_x, this.position_y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
  //I want to increase and decrease the font size and brightness of number inside the circle. How to do that?
  // drawing the circle from two pieces
  draw(ctx) {
    this.drawFill({
      ctx
    })
    this.drawOutline({
      ctx
    })
  }
  //I want to increase and decrease the font size and brightness of number inside the circle. How to do that?
  // color change function
  setColor({
    outline,
    fill
  }) {
    this.color = outline
    this.fillColor = fill
  }

  //I want to increase and decrease the font size and brightness of number inside the circle. How to do that?
  update(ctx) {
    this.text = this.hit_counter;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, window_width, window_height)
    this.draw(context);

    if ((this.position_x + this.radius) > window_width) {
      this.dx = -this.dx;
      this.hit_counter++;
    }

    if ((this.position_x - this.radius) < 0) {
      this.dx = -this.dx;
      this.hit_counter++;
    }

    if ((this.position_y - this.radius) < 0) {
      this.dy = -this.dy;
      this.hit_counter++;
    }

    if ((this.position_y + this.radius) > window_height) {
      this.dy = -this.dy;
      this.hit_counter++;
    }

    this.position_x += this.dx;
    this.position_y += this.dy;
  }
}
//I want to increase and decrease the font size and brightness of number inside the circle. How to do that?
const my_circle = new Circle(100, 100, 50, 3, 'Black');

const updateCircle = function(ctx) {
  requestAnimationFrame(() => updateCircle(ctx));
  my_circle.update(ctx);
}

updateCircle(context);

document.getElementById("inc").addEventListener("click", increment);
function increment() {
  my_circle.fontSize++;
}

document.getElementById("dec").addEventListener("click", decrement);
function decrement() {
  if (my_circle.fontSize - 1 >= 0) {
    my_circle.fontSize--;
  }
}

document.getElementById("bri").addEventListener("click", briincrement);
function briincrement() {
  if (my_circle.textAlpha + 0.1 <= 1) {
    my_circle.textAlpha += 0.1;
  }
}

document.getElementById("bridec").addEventListener("click", bridecrement);
function bridecrement() {
  if (my_circle.textAlpha - 0.1 >= 0) {
    my_circle.textAlpha -= 0.1;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="inc">Font +</button>
<button id="dec">Font -</button>
<button id="bri">Font brightness +</button>
<button id="bridec">Font brightness -</button>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank You So Much... ;))

Comment: No problem tpler - glad I could help! =)

Comment: Please Answer This Link Also [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70969659/i-want-to-move-the-circle-in-different-ways-such-as-horizontal-line-vertical-l)